# Redux initial state disappears on action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an initial state in my reducer which is an empty object

```
const initialState = {
    postHistory: {},
    loading: true
};
```

I've noticed that when I run a function from a different component which dispatches the action that this initial state actually disappears. This is causing me problems because in one of my components I'm trying to detect the present of data in this object.

```
const obj = this.props.postHistory;
this.props.postHistory[Object.keys(obj)[0]] && this.props.postHistory[Object.keys(obj)[0]]
```

However when the action is fired, I can see in redux that the initial state for the object has completely disappeared and only the loading value is there.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Has any one else encountered such an issue? Any advice to overcome welcome! Thank you.

Adding reducer code as suggested:

```
import { POST_HISTORY } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    postHistory: {},
    loading: true,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){

    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case POST_HISTORY :
            return {
                ...state,
                postHistory: payload.data,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add the related codes (reducer, action, the place you call action) ?

Comment: Your code for handling the action is probably wrong and is replacing your state without adding in the previous values for, eg, postHistory

Comment: first things first, learn to install Redux Devtool Extension so you can have a quick look at your store by the time before/after you call your action creator, this might help you

Comment: @Stephanie Parker , Can you paste the code of your reducer code when you call the action from other component.

Comment: Reducer code added as requested - thanks. @DucHong I already have that extension installed as mentioned in my post.

Comment: try once logging the this.props.postHistory; in console, and see what type of data assigned to the propHistory.

Comment: so, did you log out the value of `payload` before assigning to `postHistory`, and make sure it's not `undefined` or `null`. Also, check your mapStateToProps, your `postHistory` is pointing to the correct property name,

Comment: Yeah the component itself works fine on first load whilst first fetching the data and has loaded the data it's only when making a second request that it becomes an issue. logging typeof this.props.postHistory returns object, until a new request is made at which point it becomes undefined.

Comment: why do not you add parenthesees to this.props.poistHistory?  `this.props.postHistory([Object.keys(obj)[0]] && this.props.postHistory[Object.keys(obj)[0]])`

Comment: I think the issue will be here "this.props.postHistory[Object.keys(obj)[0]] && this.props.postHistory[Object.keys(o

Comment: @iLiA that returns not a function.

Comment: @VenkateshSomu that is the issue - but what's the fix is the question? :)

Comment: @StephanieParker I assume you are using `connect` and did you passed action creator as second argument ? mapDispatchToProps? (and i am concerned if you use redux-thunk)

Comment: yeah its the same component as used elsewhere in the app to make the action request. it works fine on other pages, its just this page/component that is dependent on that data to render

Comment: you can't change prop value directly inside the code, you need to assign the prop value to some variable and then filter or change inside the value and display it in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First console your payload.data....then check that the data which you are getting is in "JSON" format our string format..If the data is in "Object" form then it will store in your POSTHISTORY, and if your data is in "json" format then it will not store the data in initial state.